# How to call WS-RM Web services with Apache JMeter

Tags: web-services, jmeter, ws-reliablemessaging

How can I enable ws reliable messaging in JMeter for web services.
When I'm trying to send request in jmeter, I am getting error like mismatch endpoint but in SOAP UI tool it is working fine after enabling the ws reliable messaging option.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion,but I got some other easy solution.We can record SOAP UI request in fiddler and from their we can copy request (Request will change after enabling wsrm in soap ui) and we can use that as a final request and paste that in body of http request sampler.Parameterized required value That's it.It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll need to code your own pre-processor based on this similar code:

- https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-wssecurity/blob/master/README.md

Another option is to code in java/Groovy the call, example:

- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Web-Services-SOA/ThisdemoshowshowWSReliableMessagingsupportinApacheCXFmaybeenabled.htm

And use Groovy in JSR223 Sampler